# Wordpress - use a different domain for a certain post type

Tags: wordpress, redirect, dns, mapping, subdomain

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to have a WordPress custom post type using a different domain. For example, let's say my main site is example.com, and I have a custom post type called "Books" - is it possible to have that post type on `books.com/book-name` rather than `example.com/book-name`?

I've looked into domain mapping and redirects but I'm struggling to find a straight answer on if/how it's possible. I'd also need this to be done automatically rather than having to add redirects to the .htaccess file manually, or having to restart the server, for example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

this isn't hard, point all the domain to your wordpress install, then just use superglobal `$_SERVER` and global `$post` to perform conditional to redirect or not base on `$post->post_type`.

example; injecting the redirect login on `wp` action

```
add_action('wp', function() {
    
    global $post;
    
    //map your domain to post type
    $post_type_domain_map = [
        'books' => 'books.com',
        // not needed, just example mapping all post type to specific domain
        // 'post' => 'example.com',
        // 'page' => 'example.com'
    ];  
    
    //grab the domain name from the request; you can also use parse_url
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    
    //check if it should redirect base on following condition
    $shoud_redirect = ( 
        $post // if has valid post
        && isset( $post_type_domain_map[$post->post_type] ) // if post type is map to a domain
        && $host != $post_type_domain_map[$post->post_type] // if the request host is not the correct domain for the current post_type
    );
    
    // stop the execution if it should NOT redirect 
    if ( !$shoud_redirect ) return;

    // get the post permalink but replace the host depending on the post type
    // e.i. https://example.com/hello-world will transform to https://books.com/hello-world and vice-versa
    $domain_specific_permalink = str_replace(home_url(), $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'. $post_type_domain_map[$post->post_type], get_permalink($post));
    
    // check if headers have been set otherwise perform redirect
    if (!headers_sent()) {
        wp_redirect($domain_specific_permalink, 301);
        exit;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try. Out of interest, do you know if a similar method could be used to have specific posts running on their own domain? E.g. rather than example.com/post-name it could be running on mysite.com?